# docker apt-get got `Cannot inititate the connection to 8000:80 (...) - connect (22: Invalid Argument)`

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I was trying to run `apt-get update` in a docker container.

I got these errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch 
http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  
Cannot initiate the connection to 8000:80 (0.0.31.64). 
- connect (22: Invalid argument)

W: Failed to fetch 
http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  
Cannot initiate the connection to 8000:80 (0.0.31.64). 
- connect (22: Invalid argument)
```

I googled around, and some problems related to `docker` `apt-get` are related to *proxy settings* or *DNS settings*.  I think I have addressed both but I am still getting the above error.  Any ideas?

**proxy settings**

Error messages would be this -- I am NOT seeing these errors anymore.

```
W: Failed to fetch 
http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  
Cannot initiate the connection to ftp.osuosl.org:80 (2600:3404:200:237::2). 
- connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]
W: Failed to fetch 
https://repo.percona.com/apt/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  
Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds
```

My solution has been putting lines like these in my dockerfile.  Since 
then the error messages have changed, so I believe this is the right fix 
for the proxy problem.

```
ENV http_proxy <myCorpProxy>:8000
ENV https_proxy <myCorpProxy>:8000
```

**dns settings**

The error would be this -- I am NOT seeing these errors anymore.

```
W: Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  
Could not resolve 'my.proxy.net'
W: Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  
Could not resolve 'my.proxy.net'
W: Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  
Could not resolve 'my.proxy.net'
```

Solutions: [Fix Docker's networking DNS config](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/)

**Other forums**

I found a discussion thread on `forums.docker.com` but could not
reach a solution yet

https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-run-apt-get-update-successfully-behind-proxy-beta-13-1/14170

**Update with correct syntax of proxy settings that solved the problem!**

Thanks for Matt's answer.  I realized that the syntax that 
I was using was wrong.  They CANNOT be

```
ENV http_proxy <myCorpProxy.domain.name>:8000
ENV https_proxy <myCorpProxy.domain.name>:8000
```

but has to be

```
ENV http_proxy  http://<myCorpProxy.domain.name>:8000
ENV https_proxy http://<myCorpProxy.domain.name>:8000
```

Once I changed that, my `apt-get` started to work.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: configure your daemon DNS. What is the OS you are in ?

Comment: The OS is `Redhat 7.3`.  I think the problem is NOT related to DNS.  I could run a test `docker exec -it myContainer ping cnn.com` and it would get correct response.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your proxy settings are invalid. Running the following command produces the same error message:

```
docker run -ti --rm \
  -e https_proxy=http://8000:80 \
  -e http_proxy=http://8000:80 \
  debian apt-get update
```

You need a valid `http://hostname:port` that you can connect to as a proxy

```
docker run -ti --rm \
  -e https_proxy=http://10.8.8.8:3142 \
  -e http_proxy=http://10.8.8.8:3142 \
  debian apt-get update
```

You should be able to get some form of response from the proxy address

```
→ curl -v http://10.8.8.8:3142
* Rebuilt URL to: http://10.8.8.8:3142/
*   Trying 10.8.8.8...
* Connected to 10.8.8.8 (10.8.8.8) port 3142 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.8.8.8:3142
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 406 Usage Information
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
<
```

Comment: had the same problem. good catch it solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem on Mac OSX. I tried the solution from @[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt). I use `docker run -it -e http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1235 -e https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1235 ubuntu` to set the proxy. I got `Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:1235 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)`.

I use `docker inspect <container_id>` to get the proxy information of that container. I got `"HTTP_PROXY=docker.for.mac.localhost:1235", "HTTPS_PROXY=docker.for.mac.localhost:1235"`. I change the command to `docker run -it -e http_proxy=http://docker.for.mac.localhost:1235 -e https_proxy=http://docker.for.mac.localhost:1235 ubuntu`. It works.